# How can I clear Sonatype Nexus log files

Tags: nexus

According to the [Sonatype Nexus Docs - logging](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-log.html), I can set the logging levels (debug, warnings, errors). But how do I actually clear the logs that sit on my server without SSHing in and deleting them? They're approaching 1Gb.

Seems this should be a scheduled task, like empty the trash.

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you set up Nexus for production usage you would add them into your logrotate setup so they are not getting bigger and bigger.

The Nexus user interface has no feature to purge the log.

Answer (score 0):

A 1GB log file implies you have DEBUG logging enabled. First change back to INFO level logging of the ROOT logger using the Nexus UI, to keep the log file under control.

Automatic Log rotation and size limiting is also possible for Java Service Wrapper and Nexus logs. By default, Nexus ships with sensible log rotation defaults.

First decide which log is the problem. Then use the correct configuration to adjust this.

Java Service Wrapper - wrapper.log
http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/props-logging.html

Nexus logs configured via logback and logback-nexus.xml/logback-overrides.xml

You may find this reference helpful:
https://support.sonatype.com/entries/25427167-Nexus-Logging-Guide